# Is it possible to check if there is a lease on a specific Azure blob, using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I have a piece of code that is oftentimes run by multiple processes, in which a certain blobfile has to be updated with some new information. Because I do not want these processes to simultaneously write to this file - which would cause conflict errors - I put a lease on the file when a process starts modifying it, and want to break this lease once it is done modifying it.

Now the problem is that I have to check for each process if there is already a lease on the blobfile, and if not, keep waiting until the lease is broken and then acquire a lease for the current process. The way in which I realise this now is by running the following code:

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
if self.blob_service.exists(self.container, self.changelog):
   while True:
       try:
          self.blob_service.acquire_blob_lease(self.container, self.changelog,
                                                         lease_duration=-1)
          break
       except AzureConflictHttpError:
          pass
   self.blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(self.container, self.changelog, stream)
   stream.seek(0)

   .... do some processing and write to blobfile
   self.blob_service.break_blob_lease(self.container, self.changelog)
```

`blob_service` here is an instance of `BlockBlobService`. However this results in a continuous stream of logging of `2020-04-19 16:19:51,517 ERROR Client-Request-ID=d53b7e6e-8248-11ea-a073-dca90492a6b8 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Sun, 19 Apr 2020 14:19:50 GMT, Server-Request-ID=c339439f-e01e-0058-1d55-16e3bc000000, HTTP status code=409, Exception=There is already a lease present. ErrorCode: LeaseAlreadyPresent<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>LeaseAlreadyPresent</Code><Message>There is already a lease present.RequestId:c339439f-e01e-0058-1d55-16e3bc000000Time:2020-04-19T14:19:51.5047575Z</Message></Error>.`
This will go on until process 1 breaks the lease and process 2 can acquire the lease.

Now of course there are ways to suppress this logging, but I would much rather be able to do something like this.

```
while True:
    if self.blob_service.blob_has_lease(self.container, self.changelog):
        continue
    else:
        self.blob_service.acquire_blob_lease(self.container, self.changelog,
                                                         lease_duration=-1)
```

In `if self.blob_service.blob_has_lease(self.container, self.changelog)` is something that I have made up myself. However I can not in any way find such a method or property for checking if a certain blob has a lease on it currently. Is there any such method or workaround in which I could write my code like the example I have provided above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can possibly call [`get_blob_properties`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L1587) method to get the properties of a blob. If a blob is leased, then you should get some value in [`lease`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/models.py#L122) variable under [`blob's properties`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/models.py#L90).

Answer (score 0):

Azure.Storage.Blobs V12 will have you working with the `BlobClient`.  I found this to work:

```
BlobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, new BlobRequestConditions() { LeaseId = lease.LeaseId }, new CancellationToken());
```

I hope this SDK lasts longer than six months. I started with Azure about seven months ago; everything I learned then is "Legacy". Oh well.